# Which software can be used for diagrams incorporated in latex and html

Tags: graphics, graphs, html, latex2html

I need to draw one or a few flow-diagram like graph which must be included in a PDF produced with Latex and a HTML file shown in a browser.

What is the best option for the software? I would prefer a package to describe the graph in text.

Comment: You could use tikz in a standalone document to create your diagram. Include it as pdf in your latex document and as svg in your html

Comment: To add, many here use imagemagick https://imagemagick.org/index.php to convert such standalone drawings e.g. from .pdf to .png or .jpg . It's free and works like a charm. // E.g. editor TexMaker allows to save its preview as bitmap, while quality isn't always what you want.